# SSL on DigitalOcean without Apache or Nginix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, digital-ocean

Ok, I am very new to this, so I'm very sorry If what I say does not make sense. I'm a ruby on rails developer and I want to host my web application using Digital Ocean. Now I installed Ubuntu 18.04, and I followed this article to deploy my rails app to my web server:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/standalone/oss/install_language_runtime.html

This article explains how to deploy a ruby on rails app to Digital Ocean using a library called `Passenger`. Nowhere in the installation do we install `Apache` or `Nginx`.

This is where the problem lies... Every tutorial or article I find are explanations on how to configure an SSL certificate with either Apache or Nginx. They use libraries such as Let's Encrypt. But, like I said, I'm not using Apache or Nginx. I'm using Passenger.

How can I implement an SSL certificate on my digital ocean droplet without needing Apache or Nginx. Or if any of you have any articles that can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it if you could share them. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found it or not but this is the official tutorial: [Using SSL with Passenger in Production](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/prod_ssl.html)

Comment: Thats a little funny. Part of the tutorial uses Nginx. I don't have Nginx so it didn't work for me... I'll keep looking. thanks!

Comment: keep going through the tutorial... you'll find that you need to install Nginx in a couple of steps. Passenger is your ruby language interpreter, so to speak, not a webserver. What you've done so far is allow your droplet to interpret your Ruby code, but not serve it over the web. (this is the equivalent of installing PHP or php-fpm or something like that and expect to serve it to the web without Apache or Nginx... two different things :) )

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Omg yes. Thank you, that really was the explanation I needed. I didn't really know what Passenger was. I'll keep going. Thank you so much.